# How do you create a table in python from a text file

Tags: python

i have been trying to create a table from a text file like this:

```
MemberID  Surname  Year joined  Membership status  Nights booked  Pointsbalance
Jim123    jimmy     2017        gold               10              15000
```

and the text file is like this:

```
jim123,jimmy,2017,gold,10,15000
```

how would i do this? 
as simple as possible please

Comment: Do you want to print out the table or store it as a dictionary?

Comment: The title and the content of your question mismatch. Do you want to create a table from a text file as the title suggest, or create a second text file from the first one, as your question says ?

Comment: To be able to split without getting empty elements when a separator is repeated I use the 're' module like this : `thelist = re.split('\s+',thestring)`. This splits on any amount of "white space like" characters, so it also works in case your file has mixed space/tabulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the data and put it in a dictionary:

```
f = open('filename.txt').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in f]

final_data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in f}
```

Comment: when i run your code it only print the first letter, how would i print the whole word regardless of its length

Comment: @Nathan what results did you get? I got `{'jim123': ['jimmy', '2017', 'gold', '10', '15000']}`. Is that what you want?

Comment: i do get what u got but there are multiple lines of that and i want each of them to be under the correct subheading

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using the data for any kind of analysis, try checking out **Pandas**. Check out this great (and detailed) post on how to achieve what you are trying to do:

https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv.html

This is the code you want (but check out that URL for the explanation):

```
df = pd.read_csv('../data/jimmy.csv', names=['MemberID', 'Surname', 'Membership status', 'Nights booked', 'Pointsbalance'])
```

`df`

or

```
raw_data = {'MemberID': ['Jim123', 'Calamari123'],
        'Surname': ['jimmy', 'calamari'],
        'Membership status': ['gold', 'platinum'],
        'Nights booked': [10, 24],
        'Pointsbalance': ["15000", "94,000"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['MemberID', 'Surname', 'Membership status', 'Nights booked', 'Pointsbalance'])
```

Comment: i can only use python, not pandas thanks for the help though